# Page not found error in laravel routing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am new to `laravel`, I have written a route

```
Route::resource('contract', 'ContractController');
Route::group(['prefix' => 'contract'], function () {
    Route::get('data', 'ContractController@data');
});
```

My controller file is :

```
public function data(Datatables $datatables)
{
    $contracts = $this->contractRepository->getAll()
        ->get()
        ->map(function ($contract) {
            return [
                'id' => $contract->id,
                'start_date' => $contract->start_date,
                'end_date' => $contract->end_date,
                'description' => $contract->description,
                'name' =>  '',
                'user' => '',
            ];
        });

    return $datatables->collection($contracts)
        ->addColumn('actions', '@if(Sentinel::getUser()->hasAccess([\'contracts.write\']) || Sentinel::inRole(\'admin\'))
                                    <a href="{{ url(\'contract/\' . $id . \'/edit\' ) }}"  title="{{ trans(\'table.edit\') }}">
                                        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-pencil text-warning"></i> </a>
                                        @endif
                                 @if(Sentinel::getUser()->hasAccess([\'contracts.read\']) || Sentinel::inRole(\'admin\'))
                                 <a href="{{ url(\'contract/\' . $id . \'/show\' ) }}" title="{{ trans(\'table.details\') }}" >
                                        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-eye text-primary"></i> </a>
                                @endif
                                @if(Sentinel::getUser()->hasAccess([\'contracts.delete\']) || Sentinel::inRole(\'admin\'))
                                    <a href="{{ url(\'contract/\' . $id . \'/delete\' ) }}"  title="{{ trans(\'table.delete\') }}">
                                        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-times text-danger"></i></a>
                                 @endif')
        ->removeColumn('id')
        ->escapeColumns( [ 'actions' ] )->make();
}
```

When I am running with url `contract/data` then I am getting `404 not found` error. In console I am getting error also

```
No query results for model [App\Models\Contract].
```

Please help me to resolve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `Route::resource('contract', 'ContractController');` or put that after `Route::group(['prefix' => 'contract'], function () {
    Route::get('data', 'ContractController@data');
});` like so:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'contract'], function () {
    Route::get('data', 'ContractController@data');
});
Route::resource('contract', 'ContractController');
```

You get 404 on route `/contract/data` because the router is actually directed into `contract/{contract}` in `ContractController@show` from the upper routes on `Route::resource('contract', 'ContractController');`